# android viewpager: reset adjacent fragment's scroll position

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm using viewpager and SlidingTabLayout for implementing tabs in my activity. The activity has 5 fragments. What I'm trying to achieve is as soon as when the user starts scrolling to switch tabs, I need to reset the scrollY of the new fragment (that is already in memory due to viewpager caching but just becoming visible) to a certain value.

I tried using Fragment.onResume but it does not work. Using ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged, I'm able to capture when the user starts scrolling to the left/right, but how do I access the new fragment that is just becoming visible so I can reset it's scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ViewPager.PageTransformer` to take the coming page then do whatever you wanted, just like this :

```
@Override
public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
    page.setScrollY(100);
    ...
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26192465/1294681) question and answers would tell you the details.

Comment: I tried this but it is setting the scrollY of the current tab (outgoing) and not the new one coming in. I want to reset the scrollY of the tab that is just becoming visible.

Comment: you haven't pay enough attention on the `transformPage` method, it would informing both of current page and becoming page, you only need to decide which position you want to dealing with and which should be ignore. [here](https://github.com/vince-styling/parallel-swipe-listview/blob/master/src/com/vincestyling/parallel_swipe_listview/MainActivity.java#LC79) is a clear sample.

Comment: Vince, I tried using "if(position > 0 && position <= 1)" but it only tells if it is a Left to Right or Right to Left swipe, how can I tell if the view is the new one vs the current one? Thanks.

Comment: follow the [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#zoom-out).